# Ionic Native Storage - Get Specific Key Values In a Single Promise

Tags: ionic-framework, promise, ionic-native, cordova-nativestorage

I am using Ionic Native Storage:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/

I am saving Form Values in storage as

*Key: form-xxxx-xxxx (Some id as xxxx-xxxx)

Value: Some Object*

Now in order to get an item from Native Storage, I will use `Storage.getItem(Key)`. Now this method returns a promise for fetching each item.
I don't want to iterate over keys and return a promise for every single item since I need to show some list *(Saved Form List)*. How can I achieve it with returning a single promise and get my values?

**Sadly, there is no such method to get a list of Keys, given an Array of Keys for Native Storage** :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Promise.all` as per [this web page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).